# Implementing a NavigationDrawer in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I would like to implement a `NavigationDrawer` in my application. I am currently using `ActionBarSherlock` with the following code:

```
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    String tab_station_list = getResources().getString(
            R.string.tab_station_list);

    // @Darshak ------------
    String tab_radio_online = getResources().getString(
            R.string.tab_radio_online);
    // ---------------------

    String tab_facebook = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_facebook);
    String tab_twitter = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_twitter);
    String tab_about = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_about);

    // @Darshak ------------

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab_radio_online, tab_radio_online,
            FragmentPlayer.class, null);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab_station_list, tab_station_list, TVDetail.class,
            null);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab_facebook, tab_facebook,
            FacebookActivity.WebviewFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab_twitter, tab_twitter,
            TwitterActivity.WebviewFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab_about, tab_about,
            AboutActivity.WebviewFragment.class, null);

    displayAd = Boolean.parseBoolean(getResources().getString(
            R.string.is_display_ad));
    displayAd();
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mContext;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(String tag, CharSequence label, Class<?> clss,
            Bundle args) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = mContext.getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText(label);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mContext.getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mContext.getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabSelected(com
     * .actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab,
     * android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mContext.getSupportActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabUnselected(com
     * .actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab,
     * android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabReselected(com
     * .actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab,
     * android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

What do I need to change in order to show a `NavigationDrawer`?

Also, should I make my app compatible with Android 2.X and 3.X?
I plan on providing compatibility with Lolipop.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that you should not use the `ActionbarSherlock` library in a new project. Contemporary Material design guidelines suggest using a `Toolbar` instead of an `Actionbar`.

Second, there are a few tutorials demonstrating the implementation of a `NavigationDrawer` in your application. I would personally recommend the tutorial from Google posted [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Keep in mind the `NavigationDrawer` should be displayed above the `Toolbar`.

Third, I would suggest that you do not provide support for Android 2.X or 3.X unless you have the time to do so. As of writing this, Android devices running an Android version below 4.0 make up less than 8% of the market. This percentage will decline over time so you will have to judge whether or not it is worth it to support these devices. You can find current Android version statistics [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: you think i would need to write my app from scratch or will be easy to modify it to use navigation drawer? thank you

Comment: That depends, if you have just started your app I would recommend starting over. I think Android Studio offers a template for a NavigationDrawer but I could be mistaken. If you are far along in your app the NavigationDrawer is easy enough to implement, just follow the tutorial I linked you too. You can also download the entire project from that tutorial.